# Check if two JSON have same values for their common names

Tags: c#, json

I need a good design to solve this problem.

I get two separate `JSON` strings each time I call a web API. Let name them `recieve1` and `recieve2`.  I need to check for **all the common names** of `recieve1` and `recieve2`, if they have the same values. If there are some name value pair in `recieve2` that are not present in `recieve1` that is okay(and vice versa). But I do not know the name value pairs of the json strings. Because I can possibly get new pair of `JSON` each time I call that api. For example, on the first call I can get this

`recieve1`:

```
{
  "employees": [
    {
      "firstName": "John",
      "lastName": "Doe"
    },
    {
      "firstName": "Anna",
      "lastName": "Smith"
    },
    {
      "firstName": "Peter",
      "lastName": "Jones"
    }
  ]
}
```

`recieve2`:

```
{
  "employees": [
    {
      "firstName": "John",
      "lastName": "Doe",
      "Sex": "Male"

    },
    {
      "firstName": "Anna",
      "lastName": "Smith"
    },
    {
      "firstName": "Peter",
      "lastName": "Jones",
      "age":  "100"   // recieve1 does not have this name value pair
                      // But that is Ok they are still equivalent
    }
  ]
}
```

By my requirement these two are “equivalent”. Let’s look at another example of equivalent JSONs, on the second call we get,
`recieve1`:

```
{"menu": 
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Second Call Return",
    "ReturnCanHaveArrays": {
      "array": [
        {"isCommon": "Yes", "id": "1"},
        {"isCommon ": "Yes", "id": "4"},
        {"isCommon": "No", "id": "100"}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

`recieve2`:

```
{"menu": 
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Second Call Return",
    "newProperty" : "This is not present in recieve1. But that is ok"
    "ReturnCanHaveArrays": {
      "array": [
        {"isCommon": "Yes", "id": "1"},
        {"isCommon ": "Yes", "id": "4"}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Above two jsons are also equivalent. But following two are not:

`recieve1`:

```
{"menu": {
  "id": "1"
}}
```

`recieve2`:

```
{"menu": {
  "id": "10" // not equivalent.
}}
```

As you can see I can not determine the property sets up handed. How can I solve this problem?

- Language: c# (important. **Must use c#**) .
- NET version: not important
- Please suggest best designs for solving this problem.
- Use any technology if necessary.
  **Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JSON.net, this is fairly trivial.

```
bool AreEquiv(JObject a, JObject b)
{
    foreach (var prop in a)
    {
        JToken aValue = prop.Value;
        JToken bValue;
        if (b.TryGetValue(prop.Key, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase, out bValue))
        {
            if (aValue.GetType() != bValue.GetType())
                return false;

            if (aValue is JObject)
            {
                if (!AreEquiv((JObject)aValue, (JObject)bValue))
                    return false;
            }
            else if (!prop.Value.Equals(bValue))
                return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

This code will traverse the two `JObject`, comparing non-object values and recursively calling this function for any inner `JObject`. If a key is not found in both `a` and `b`, it is skipped.